# Vivado Logic Analyzer Waveform Procedure

Tags: sdk, xilinx, vivado

I have been using Vivado Logic Analyzer for months. and believe me it took so much time to properly see the debug singals on waveform.  I usually mark the debug signals on block design and then synthesize and generate bitstream . But sometimes i can see my clock on debug "FCLK" or sometimes "ProcessingSystemFCLK, using (Setup_debug on synthesized designs ) . Then also sometimes i can see proper transiitons of waveform on ILA , and sometimes i can see only one straight value there;  No transiitons whatsoever. Sometimes I get LUTRAM error and sometimes the bit stream generated successfully.

It will be appreciated if one can tell me the proper sequence for debugging signals and whether first to program device using Vivado or using SDK. And also kindly clarify above points too.

thanks so much

Regards

Comment: Have you read [UG908 - Programming and Debugging](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_1/ug908-vivado-programming-debugging.pdf)?

Comment: Its regarding Vivado Lab. I am using Vivado 2014.4. And I read their documentation too :/

Answer (score 0):

There are many bugs lurking in the Vivado ILA code, I've run into many myself. I have had the most success generating the ILA in a managed IP project and manually instantiating it in the RTL (use the example project to get a template). That way you can be sure what clock it is running on. If you are getting different clocks I would guess this is why your probes seem to behave differently.

If your device is getting full, Vivado can sometimes fail routing with large ILA blocks. If you rerun the build you may get different results.

As far as programming it, it doesn't matter if it is programmed with Vivado or SDK, but Hardware Manager only exists in Vivado, so you'll need to bring this up and point to the .ltx file to view the probes (don't forget to refresh the device).